# Add first existing attachment

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I want to send hundreds of emails with different attachments.

I have written code, which will work when the attachment exists.
If the attachment cannot be found in the folder, the code will show an error.

My goal is if the attachment doesn't exist, skip to the next column until that column attachment does exist in the folder.

```vb
Sub autoSendingbill()

Dim openoutlook As Outlook.Application
Set openoutlook = New Outlook.Application

Dim newMail As MailItem
Dim secCol, totalCol As Integer
totalCol = Cells(1000, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For secCol = 2 To totalCol
    Set newMail = openoutlook.CreateItemFromTemplate("D:\AutoSendingBill.oft")

    With newMail
        .To = Cells(secCol, 2).Value
        .Subject = "Internet Service Monthly Fee"
        .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "Name", Cells(secCol, 1).Value)
        .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "Code", Cells(secCol, 4).Value)
        .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "ISP", Cells(secCol, 5).Value)
        .Attachments.Add Cells(secCol, 3).Value
        .Close olSave
    End With
    Next secCol
End Sub
```

Comment: At the first step inside your `For` loop, add an `If` statement to check if the file exists. You can check if a file exists by using `Dir`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either check that the file exists:

```vb
if (Dir(Cells(secCol, 3).Value) <> "") Then
  .Attachments.Add Cells(secCol, 3).Value
End If
```

Or (in case the file exists but cannot be read) catch the exception:

```vb
On Error Resume Next
.Attachments.Add Cells(secCol, 3).Value
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "An error occurred: " & Err.Description
    ' Reset the Err object
    Err.Clear
End If

' Disable error handling
On Error Goto 0
```